# Data type conversion and map object error in Python, TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'map'

Tags: casting, typeerror

I have a newbie question regard data type conversion in Python:

Assuming I have an np.array object as:

```
X = np.array([[1.,2.,0.5,2.],[2.,3.,0.7,2.],[3.,2.,0.65,1.]])
```

I wanted to convert each value in columns `[0,1,3]` into integer format using the syntax below:

```
Y = np.array(map(tuple,X),dtype=[('col0',int),('col1',int),('col2',float),('col3',int)])
```

My expectation for `Y` is an array of the same shape with `X`, but each of the list element is convert to tuple and corresponding data type for each column, i.e.,

```
Y = np.array([(1,2,0.5,2),(2,3,0.7,2),(3,2,0.65,1)])
```

However, I encountered an TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'map'

So I have 2 native questions:
1) Is the expectation for the output Y correct?
2) How to fix the TypeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your expectation for Y is correct, however if you've got a large array of different data-types, you might want to consider using a Pandas dataframe as it handles columns of different types in a much more straightforward fashion than a Numpy structured array.

Secondly, your code was very close. `map` produces a `map` object, and not a list and as the TypeError says, Numpy canot process a 'map' object. The simple solution is to wrap your `map()` with `list()` to create a list of tuples:

```
Y = np.array(list(map(tuple,X)),dtype=[('col0',int),('col1',int),('col2',float),('col3',int)])
```

Which yields:

```
array([(1, 2, 0.5 , 2), (2, 3, 0.7 , 2), (3, 2, 0.65, 1)],
      dtype=[('col0', '<i8'), ('col1', '<i8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<i8')])
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much for your help David!